# Using internal API

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

How can I use internal API in clarity > 0.10.9? In version 0.10.6, we use this imports in our project to modify internal filter in datagrid:

```
import {DatagridStringFilterImpl} from "clarity-angular/data/datagrid/built-in/filters/datagrid-string-filter-impl"; 
import {RegisteredFilter} from "clarity-angular/data/datagrid/providers/filters";
```

At least in version 0.10.9 this can not be written any more. Compiler ends up with the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/common/DatagridUtils.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'clarity-
angular/data/datagrid/providers/filters' in 'C:\java\workspace\rimc\rimc-web\src\main\webapp\angularapp\src\app\common'
 @ ./src/app/common/DatagridUtils.ts 5:16-74
 @ ./src/app/sampleData/sample-data.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts

 ERROR in ./src/app/common/DatagridUtils.ts
 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'clarity-angular/data/datagrid/built-in/filters/datagrid-string-filter-impl' in 
'C:\java\workspace\project\angularapp\src\app\common'
  @ ./src/app/common/DatagridUtils.ts 4:36-121
  @ ./src/app/sampleData/sample-data.component.ts
  @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
  @ ./src/app/index.ts
  @ ./src/main.ts
  @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
 webpack: Failed to compile.
```

We would like to upgrade to 0.10.10 due to bug 1512 resolution, I recently reported.

**Edit:** Being asked why to use internal API instead of built-in support for custom filters, here is my answer: It is because in my situation I would like to use fulltext filter represented by separate input field above datagrid. After filling up this field refresh in datagrid is triggered and request is sent to backend. The trick is, that right before triggering request I append fulltext filter value from separate input field to internal value of datagrid filter. All with help of internal API that changed in mentioned version. If there is another way to achieve this functionality, I will be glad to here from you.

**Edit 2: (source code)**

```
import {
Datagrid, DatagridPropertyComparator, DatagridPropertyStringFilter, DatagridStringFilter,
State
} from "clarity-angular";
import {DatagridStringFilterImpl} from "clarity-angular/data/datagrid/built-in/filters/datagrid-string-filter-impl";
import {FiltersProvider, RegisteredFilter} from "clarity-angular/data/datagrid/providers/filters";


export default class DatagridUtils {

static fulltextPropertyName: string = '_fulltext';

static getState(datagrid: Datagrid, fulltext: any) {

    const state: State = {};

    let activeFilters;

    if (datagrid && datagrid['filters']) {
        const page = datagrid['page'];
        if (page.size > 0) {
            state.page = {from: page.firstItem, to: page.lastItem, size: page.size};
        }

        const sort = datagrid['sort'];
        if (sort.comparator) {
            if (sort.comparator instanceof DatagridPropertyComparator) {
                /*
                 * Special case for the default object property comparator,
                 * we give the property name instead of the actual comparator.
                 */
                state.sort = {by: (<DatagridPropertyComparator>sort.comparator).prop, reverse: sort.reverse};
            } else {
                state.sort = {by: sort.comparator, reverse: sort.reverse};
            }
        }

        let filtersProvider = datagrid['filters'];
        let fulltextFilter = this.getFulltextFilter(filtersProvider);
        if (!fulltextFilter) {
            fulltextFilter = new DatagridStringFilterImpl(new DatagridPropertyStringFilter(this.fulltextPropertyName, false));
            // rucni registrace, aby se neregistroval observer, ktery nam vse zacykluje
            const registered = new RegisteredFilter(fulltextFilter, () => {
            });
            filtersProvider['_all'].push(registered);
        }
        if (typeof fulltext === 'string') {
            fulltextFilter['value'] = fulltext;
            // zmena filtru zpusobi prechod na 1. stranku
            page.current = 1;
        }

        activeFilters = filtersProvider.getActiveFilters();
        if (activeFilters.length > 0) {
            state.filters = [];
            for (const filter of activeFilters) {
                if (filter instanceof DatagridStringFilterImpl) {
                    const stringFilter = (<DatagridStringFilterImpl>filter).filterFn;
                    if (stringFilter instanceof DatagridPropertyStringFilter) {
                        /*
                         * Special case again for the default object property filter,
                         * we give the property name instead of the full filter object.
                         */
                        state.filters.push({
                            property: (<DatagridPropertyStringFilter>stringFilter).prop,
                            value: (<DatagridStringFilterImpl>filter).value
                        });
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                state.filters.push(filter);
            }
        }
    }

    return state;

}

static getFulltextFilter(filtersProvider): DatagridStringFilterImpl {
    let all = filtersProvider['_all'];
    for (const filter of all) {

        if (filter.filter instanceof DatagridStringFilterImpl) {
            const stringFilter = (<DatagridStringFilterImpl>filter.filter).filterFn;
            if (stringFilter instanceof DatagridPropertyStringFilter) {
                if ((<DatagridPropertyStringFilter>stringFilter).prop === this.fulltextPropertyName) {
                    return filter.filter;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Why does your project depend on the internal API? Internal API is private and subject to change. You might face issues if your project depends on it. If you feel that you need a feature from the internal API, then I would suggest either requesting it by filing an issue on the Clarity Github repo or requesting for an alternative solution to the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: The datagrid provides a way for you to add your own custom filters. The idea is that you can create a filter specific to your data and specs: https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/datagrid/custom-filtering

Is there a reason you modified the internal filter instead of going in that direction?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'append fulltext filter to the internal value', can you provide a simple example with some code to demonstrate your situation?